# How to access Magento site on android application

Tags: magento-1.9, android

I have completed my magento web application.

- I want to develop an android app for my magento site.
- So I want some information about how we can do that.
- Along with that how to get 
  data from magento site through API key.

Please tell me which API should i use and what is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Magento has a very good soap API using which you can do almost every actions required for a webstore. Magento has a documentation (not a great one) on how to use the API. Follow this URL: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/introduction.html

If you enable all caches, the API should work with a good speed. If you are not satisfied with what Magento has, or need more functionality like order address edit, you can do it yourself by following the API creation documentation http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/create_your_own_api.html .